# Function Returning Undefined AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is my Controller Code:

```
///////
//Diary Notes Controller
///////
diary.controller('NotesController', ['$scope','$http', 'notesService', function ($scope, $http, notesService){

//
//Get the Notes data back from the Server
//

$scope.updateFunc = function () {

    var notes = notesService.getText();

    console.log(notes);

};

$scope.updateFunc();
```

And my Services Code:

```
diary.factory('notesService', function ($http) {

return {

    getText: function () {

        $http.get('www/getNotes.php')
            .then(
            function (payload){
                return payload.data;
            });

    }

}

});
```

Basically When I do console.log the controller returns undefined for the `notes` variable which seems awkward as when i was using the controller to get the payload it works but returning the payload from the services doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$http.get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) is asynchronous function, that returns `HttpPromise`. There are couple ways how you can get `data`

1.Pass `callback`, like this

```
diary.factory('notesService', function($http) {
  return {
    getText: function (callback) {
      $http.get('www/getNotes.php')
      .then(
        function(payload) {
          callback(payload.data);
        });

    }
  }
});


notesService.getText(function (notes) {
  console.log(notes);
});
```

2.return `promise`

```
diary.factory('notesService', function($http) {
  return {
    getText: function () {
      return $http.get('www/getNotes.php');
    }
  }
});

notesService.getText().then(
    function(payload) {
        callback(payload.data);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You get `undefined` because you're not returning anything from `getText()`. Add a return statement before the `$http` call in your method:

```
getText: function () {
    return $http.get('www/getNotes.php')
        .then(function (payload) {
            return payload.data;
         });
}
```

Afterwards call the `then` method of the promise to get the value:

```
notesService.getText().then(function(notes) {
    console.log(notes);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer .. The return was what I needed to make it work.. Now it returning promise value in Controller .. :) Thank You

Comment: You, sir, save my day.

Answer (score 1):

`$http.get` returns a [Promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Since the promise callback in `then` is async, you need to handle the promise in the controller. To do this, first return the promise in the factory:

```
return $http.get('www/getNotes.php')  <-- return added at the beginning of this line
.then(function (payload){
    return payload.data;
});
```

And then, handle the promise in the controller:

```
$scope.updateFunc = function () {   
    notesService.getText().then(function(notes) {     
        console.log(notes);
    });;
};
```

Comment: Can promise be handled in factory instead of controller??

Comment: What do you mean by *handled*?  It is async.

Comment: I mean if I can process the returned values and add it into an array .etc

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are not returning anything on the getText function. If you return the promise from the $http.get the you should implement any of the promise methods to fulfill your model variable notes

```
  diary.factory('notesService', function ($http) {

    return {

        getText: function () {

            return $http.get('www/getNotes.php')
                .then(
                function (payload){
                    return payload.data;
                });

             }

          }
   });
```